# How to make a folder in chosen path matlab gui

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

I have created a gui that contain two pushbutton and two edit box. The first pushbutton and edit box is for choosing a path/directory where I can put my project folder.

The second pushbutton and edit box is for creating the project fold. If I input 'text' in the edit box and push the second button I end up creating the folder 'text' in the chosen path.

So far, my gui only working in choosing path using uigetdir, but I couldnt make the folder in that path. Could someone help me? sorry for bad english

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mkdir.html ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I already try mkdir, but I dont know how to link the folder into the chosen path. Maybe you can help me with the function/callback? Thank you for answering my question btw